# i dont know how can i use passport-local-mongoose plugin

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

this is little code from my app.js:

```
app.get('/clientes', clientes.index);
app.post('/clientes/create', clientes.create);
app.get('/clientes/add', clientes.add);
app.get('/clientes/destroy/:id', clientes.destroy);
app.get('/clientes/show/:id', clientes.show)
app.get('/clientes/edit/:id', clientes.edit);
app.post('/clientes/update/:id', clientes.update);
app.post('/clientes/list', clientes.list);
    // Login
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
        res.render('login', { user : req.user });
    });
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
    });
```

login works, if i put the correct user and pass redirect to / if not UNAUTORIZED, but how can i know in all app.gets if the user is autenticated?

i try this:

```
app.get('/clientes', passport.authenticate ( "local" ) ,clientes.index);
```

cliente.index is a controller in app/controllers/clientes.js file

But it doesn't work

i want the user need to be authenticated in all routes.

Answer (score 1):

Now is working. I show you:

first:

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/login');
}
```

a then:

```
app.get('/clientes', ensureAutenticated, clientes.index)
```